# Praat: remove pitch points and publish resynthesis using a script

Tags: praat

I generated a pure tone (440 Hz) with Praat and tried to change its pitch to 277.1826309768721 Hz (Middle C) and then to 220 Hz using a script. However, the script crashes either at "Remove pitch point(s)" (says `Command "Remove point(s)" not available for current selection`) or at "Publish resynthesis" (`Command "Publish resynthesis" not available for current selection`), whichever comes first at the script.

Here are two versions of the script, one which tries to publish the resynthesis:

```
Create Sound as pure tone: "tone", 1, 0, 0.4, 44100, 440, 0.2, 0.01, 0.01
To Manipulation: 0.01, 75, 600
Create PitchTier: "empty", 0, 1
View & Edit
Add point... 0 277.1826309768721
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier empty"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
View & Edit
Publish resynthesis
```

and one which does not try to publish the resynthesis (as it doesn't work) but tries to change the location of the pitch point instead, and fails at that:

```
Create Sound as pure tone: "tone", 1, 0, 0.4, 44100, 440, 0.2, 0.01, 0.01
To Manipulation: 0.01, 75, 600
Create PitchTier: "empty", 0, 1
View & Edit
Add point... 0 277.1826309768721
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier empty"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
View & Edit
Remove point(s)
Add point at: 0, 220
selectObject: "PitchTier empty"
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier empty"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
View & Edit
```

My ultimate goal is to write a script that takes a Manipulation object, generates monotonized versions of the sound with all the piano key frequencies from small C (130.8127826502993 Hz) up to B5 (987.7666025122483 Hz) and saves them to a folder. This cannot be done if removing pitch points or publishing resyntheses are not allowed in scripts.

And yes, I did try this by editing a Manipulation object itself, but since it didn't work, I switched to the approach of creating a Pitch tier.

By the way, I've also tried things like this:

```
s$ = selected$("Sound")
m$ = selected$("Manipulation")
selectObject: s$
endtime = Get end time
selectObjcet: m$
Remove points between... 0 endtime
```

to get started, but this resulted in a `No object named "tone"` error even though I had selected a Sound and a Manipulation named `tone`.

Comment: I found in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20587320/pitch-modification-in-praat that instead of "Publish resynthesis" you need to write "Get resynthesis (overlap-add)", but whatever I tried, it always failed.

Answer (score 0):

OK, with a little more trying I managed to create a super ugly workaround. The following script does what I wanted, but it also renames the original manipulation object to "tone" in order to be able to refer to it in the future. I'm not sure what happens if you already have objects named "tone" open... be careful.

All frequencies are hard-coded. So what this does is that it takes a manipulation object renames it to "tone", moves its pitch to the pitch of C3, saves the resynthesis as `c3.wav`, moves the pitch to C#3, saves the resynthesis as `c-sharp3.wav`, moves the pitch to D3, saves it to `d3.wav`... all the way to B5. `<folder_path>` needs to be replaced with the desired destination folder.

```
s$ = selected$("Manipulation")
Rename: "tone"
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Extract original sound
endtime = Get end time
Remove
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Extract pitch tier
View & Edit
Remove points between: 0, endtime
View & Edit
Add point: 0, 130.8127826502993
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\c3.wav"
Remove
selectObject: "PitchTier tone"
Remove point: 1
Add point: 0, 138.59131548843604
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\c-sharp3.wav"
Remove
selectObject: "PitchTier tone"
Remove point: 1
Add point: 0, 146.8323839587038
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\d3.wav"
Remove
selectObject: "PitchTier tone"
Remove point: 1
Add point: 0, 155.56349186104046
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\d-sharp3.wav"
Remove
selectObject: "PitchTier tone"
Remove point: 1
Add point: 0, 164.81377845643496
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\e3.wav"
Remove
selectObject: "PitchTier tone"
Remove point: 1
Add point: 0, 174.61411571650194
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\f3.wav"
Remove
selectObject: "PitchTier tone"
Remove point: 1
Add point: 0, 184.9972113558172
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\f-sharp3.wav"
Remove
selectObject: "PitchTier tone"
Remove point: 1
Add point: 0, 195.99771799087463
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\g3.wav"
Remove
selectObject: "PitchTier tone"
Remove point: 1
Add point: 0, 207.65234878997256
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\g-sharp3.wav"
Remove
selectObject: "PitchTier tone"
Remove point: 1
Add point: 0, 220.0
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\a3.wav"
Remove
selectObject: "PitchTier tone"
Remove point: 1
Add point: 0, 233.08188075904496
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\a-sharp3.wav"
Remove
selectObject: "PitchTier tone"
Remove point: 1
Add point: 0, 246.94165062806206
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\b3.wav"
Remove
selectObject: "PitchTier tone"
Remove point: 1
Add point: 0, 261.6255653005986
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\c4.wav"
Remove
selectObject: "PitchTier tone"
Remove point: 1
Add point: 0, 277.1826309768721
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\c-sharp4.wav"
Remove
selectObject: "PitchTier tone"
Remove point: 1
Add point: 0, 293.6647679174076
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\d4.wav"
Remove
selectObject: "PitchTier tone"
Remove point: 1
Add point: 0, 311.1269837220809
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\d-sharp4.wav"
Remove
selectObject: "PitchTier tone"
Remove point: 1
Add point: 0, 329.6275569128699
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\e4.wav"
Remove
selectObject: "PitchTier tone"
Remove point: 1
Add point: 0, 349.2282314330039
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\f4.wav"
Remove
selectObject: "PitchTier tone"
Remove point: 1
Add point: 0, 369.9944227116344
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\f-sharp4.wav"
Remove
selectObject: "PitchTier tone"
Remove point: 1
Add point: 0, 391.99543598174927
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\g4.wav"
Remove
selectObject: "PitchTier tone"
Remove point: 1
Add point: 0, 415.3046975799451
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\g-sharp4.wav"
Remove
selectObject: "PitchTier tone"
Remove point: 1
Add point: 0, 440.0
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\a4.wav"
Remove
selectObject: "PitchTier tone"
Remove point: 1
Add point: 0, 466.1637615180899
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\a-sharp4.wav"
Remove
selectObject: "PitchTier tone"
Remove point: 1
Add point: 0, 493.8833012561241
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\b4.wav"
Remove
selectObject: "PitchTier tone"
Remove point: 1
Add point: 0, 523.2511306011972
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\c5.wav"
Remove
selectObject: "PitchTier tone"
Remove point: 1
Add point: 0, 554.3652619537442
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\c-sharp5.wav"
Remove
selectObject: "PitchTier tone"
Remove point: 1
Add point: 0, 587.3295358348151
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\d5.wav"
Remove
selectObject: "PitchTier tone"
Remove point: 1
Add point: 0, 622.2539674441618
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\d-sharp5.wav"
Remove
selectObject: "PitchTier tone"
Remove point: 1
Add point: 0, 659.2551138257398
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\e5.wav"
Remove
selectObject: "PitchTier tone"
Remove point: 1
Add point: 0, 698.4564628660078
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\f5.wav"
Remove
selectObject: "PitchTier tone"
Remove point: 1
Add point: 0, 739.9888454232688
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\f-sharp5.wav"
Remove
selectObject: "PitchTier tone"
Remove point: 1
Add point: 0, 783.9908719634985
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\g5.wav"
Remove
selectObject: "PitchTier tone"
Remove point: 1
Add point: 0, 830.6093951598903
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\g-sharp5.wav"
Remove
selectObject: "PitchTier tone"
Remove point: 1
Add point: 0, 880.0
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\a5.wav"
Remove
selectObject: "PitchTier tone"
Remove point: 1
Add point: 0, 932.3275230361799
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\a-sharp5.wav"
Remove
selectObject: "PitchTier tone"
Remove point: 1
Add point: 0, 987.7666025122483
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
plusObject: "PitchTier tone"
Replace pitch tier
selectObject: "Manipulation tone"
Get resynthesis (overlap-add)
Save as WAV file: "<folder_path>\b5.wav"
Remove
```